# SPARQL federated query "SERVICE" returns Virtuoso RDFZZ Error: unexpected variable name 'stubvar14'

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, federated-queries

I want to get a list of Persons from two different SPARQL-Endpoints, so I'm using this query on [de.dbpedia](http://de.dbpedia.org/sparql):

```
PREFIX category-en: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
SELECT distinct *
WHERE {
?name dcterms:subject category-de:Haus_Liechtenstein.
?name rdf:type foaf:Person.
SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
?name dcterms:subject category-en:Princely_Family_of_Liechtenstein.
?name rdf:type foaf:Person.
}
MINUS {?name dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?d}
}
```

I get then the following error:

> Virtuoso RDFZZ Error DB.DBA.SPARQL_REXEC('http://dbpedia.org/sparql',
>   ...) has received result with unexpected variable name 'stubvar14'

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that although both these queries work fine separately, but the `service` part in the combined query is trying to filter the first set based on the second set. I think what you are missing is a union:

```
PREFIX category-en: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
SELECT distinct count(?name)
WHERE {
{
    ?name dcterms:subject category-de:Haus_Liechtenstein.
    ?name rdf:type foaf:Person.
}
union{
    SERVICE silent <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>{
    ?name dcterms:subject category-en:Princely_Family_of_Liechtenstein.
    ?name rdf:type foaf:Person.
}
}
MINUS {?name dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?d}
}
```